# When a company reports its earnings, when does the SEC EDGAR system show the report online?

Tags: regulation, sec, corporate-earnings, electronic-filing, edgar

I am looking at a stock right now Ascent Solar Technologies Inc which according to the Calendar of US Earnings was supposed to report their earnings before the market opened today on August 12.

So I checked EDGAR and it says the most recent document published was released on August 11, and is a statement of acquisitions and beneficial ownership.

Comment: Not sure, but did they report earnings? OTC companies aren't really obligated to report and so it doubles the incentive to not report especially if the numbers aren't rosy. I'm laughing because a lot of companies have obviously poor management but their beliebers can't see it.

Comment: according to this: https://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/today.html

Comment: Earnings Report dates from third parties are just estimates based on some algorithm or historical release dates.

Comment: @NuWin the algorithm of a quarter after they last reported

Comment: @CQM your right. A wise person would expect it every quarter. 4 times a year if my math is right. But Zacks uses an "algorithm" to determine when ERs are released..

Comment: The Form 10-Q was eventually filed on August 15, 2016: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350102/000135010216000180/0001350102-16-000180-index.htm

Answer (score 1):

IT appears the company you're talking about did not report as you expected them to, which is not unusual for OTC companies because, as Milo stated, they are not well-managed.

That being said, reports on EDGAR are available as soon as they're posted.  I'm not aware of any lag between when the company uploads their report and it is available on the EDGAR site.

Looking at the profile of the company you're referring to, I'm curious why you'd be so interested in a company with huge negative earnings, a near-zero share price, and an obviously spotty history of reporting its numbers.  In order to make any money with this stock, you'd have to buy a huge number of shares, which could be difficult to unload.  Further, the fees you're going to pay to make your trades are very likely to outstrip your return, so you'd be upside down on it.

This company has pretty negative financials, and in a world of cheap oil, alternative energy (and the companies that deal in it) are out of vogue, so they're not likely to see a turnaround anytime soon.  They're spending money on R & D at a rate almost 17 times earnings, and the losses are deepening, while revenues are not improving all that much.  These guys are bleeding to death, and there's little prospect of a financial transfusion on the horizon.

This is, as they say, a "dog with fleas", so your best bet is to find something else to put your money into.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!